# How can compound csv file datas in ruby on rails oop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I want to compound datas in ruby on rails.

I have a department.csv file and it is like this:
[image]

I also have person.csv file and it is like this:
[image]

Now, I have this class:

```
filepath = "#{__dir__}/../csv/department.csv"
CSV.foreach(filepath, headers: true) do |row|
  department = Department.new(
    row["name"],
    row["midterm_score_ratio"],
    row["final_score_ratio"],
    row["minimum_passing_score"],
    row["university_name"],
    "students",
    "teachers"
  )
  department.print_department_name
end
```

here, students and teachers do not exist in department.csv file. I need to fetch it from person.csv file. But also, the department is important. For example, If the person study mathematics, then here "students" must be mathematics students. How can I do this using OOP in ruby on rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group students and teachers by departments, before parse `deparment.csv` and then paste it in the Department initialization. It will look like:

```rb
# export people from person.csv
people = []
filepath = "#{__dir__}/../csv/person.csv"
CSV.foreach(filepath, headers: true) do |row|
  people << row.to_h
  student << person if person['field_of_study'] == 'student'
  teachers << person if person['field_of_study'] == 'teacher'
end

# group people by teachers/students and by department_name

people_grouped_by_field_of_study = people.group_by{|person| person['field_of_study']}

students = people_grouped_by_field_of_study['student'] # get only students
students = students.group_by{|student| student['department_name']} # group students by department_name

teachers = people_grouped_by_field_of_study['teacher'] # get only teachers
teachers = teachers.group_by{|teacher| teacher['department_name']} # group teachers by department_name


# push students and teachers based on department name
filepath = "#{__dir__}/../csv/department.csv"
CSV.foreach(filepath, headers: true) do |row|
  department = Department.new(
    row["name"],
    row["midterm_score_ratio"],
    row["final_score_ratio"],
    row["minimum_passing_score"],
    row["university_name"],
    students['name'], # students from department name
    teachers['name'] # teachers from department name
  )
  department.print_department_name
end
```

But I'm not sure about the format of students and teachers array. You need to convert it into the right format.